# RoR: defining a class inside a view helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have a view helper file, app/helpers/analysis_helper.rb, whose toplevel methods I've been using in various view files.  Works fine.  I then defined an AnalysisSummary class inside analysis_helper.rb to package up some view-specific functionality.

However, when I try to instantiate an AnalysisSummary in a view file, I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::AnalysisSummary
```

Perhaps Rails is telling me that I shouldn't be defining a class inside a helper file?  If so, where would you suggest parking AnalysisSummary?  It's not a controller, it's not a model...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it need to be a class? Why not just a collection of methods? That's what a helper is: a collection of helpful methods. Business logic does not belong in helpers. You can place your code in a module within the helper file if you want to give some more structure and organization, though.

You can put classes in `app/models` without it having to be an ActiveRecord class, but you should seriously consider what the purpose of your class is before you place it there.

If it concerns only rendering the view, and not accessing data directly, it belongs in the view or a view helper.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: I could have been more explicit: the class encapsulates three models, and extracts the bits of information I need for my views.  Since it contains instances, a collection of methods alone wouldn't help. And as for "it belongs in the view or view helper", um, it *is* in a view helper.  At least, that's my intention.

Comment: Are you saying it _applies_ to the views of three models or it _takes data from_ three models?

Comment: takes data from the three models.

Comment: It shouldn't be in a view then. The view shouldn't access models directly, that's the controllers job. The view should only access data from models through variables given to it by the controller.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Isn't that like saying a view shouldn't access @user directly, since @user is a model?  What I'm doing isn't that different.

Comment: `@user` isn't a model, it's a variable that is an instance of a model. Calling something like `User.all` is accessing the model.

Comment: So after a good walk and some dinner, I think the best thing to do is treat it as a specialized model, simply one that gathers the bits of data I need from other models.  So into app/models it shall go.  Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 8):

In [Railscasts #213 (Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast) (subscribers only link, alas), Ryan Bates provides an example of how (and why) you might include a class within a helper. The basic gist is this:

```
# app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today)
    Calendar.new(self, date).render
  end

  class Calendar
    def render
      # Calendar, render thyself
    end
    # ... additional methods called by #render
  end
end
```

To those opposed to classes within helpers, what do you make of Ryan's choice? Helpers are for generating markup, right? So if all the logic within class pertains to rendering (rather complicated) HTML, I would think that what it *does* (as opposed to what it *is*) makes it appropriate for inclusion in a helper.

Comment: This was a nice solution that continued to encapsulate all of the helper logic within a single file while also giving it more structure and form. Thanks! (and thank you Ryan!)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the class by explicitely mentioning the helper name

```
ApplicationHelper::AnalysisSummary.new
```

But I dont think it is a good idea to have classes in helpers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a module then :) Definately do not define classes inside helpers. Jsut use a simple module to do the job.